# Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols' in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-ndk

When I am trying to run my flutter app on a device my build fails to give this error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.  
NDK at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle did not have a source.properties file
```

I have ndk version
23.0.7421159rc5 installed.
Here's the result of flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

Please help to resolve the issue

Comment: Thanks for posting the github link. I found the workaround there.

Comment: some times it is solving by removing ndk from local.properties.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Go inside your `SDK` location and find the directory called **ndk** then delete the content inside that directory. Then build the app again. Probably the **ndk** version has corrupted and Android Studio will replace it with the latest.

Comment: This solution is for Unable to find bundled Java version error in your terminal. Its from `August 9, 2021`

Check the link for the solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68703869/8555332

Answer (score 15):

You can resolve this issue by the following steps,

1. In **build.gradle** file add `ndkVersion`

   ```
   android {
        ...
        ndkVersion '21.1.6528147'
   }
   ```
2. In **local.properties** remove `ndk.dir`

   ```
   ndk.dir=~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
   ```

If still issue occurs then you have to remove the ndk folder from your machine.

1. Take you run command window (Win + R) and type `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\SDK`. Or you can type the same in the file explorer address bar, then open the ndk folder from there.
   If you installed ndk in a different directory, then open that folder.
2. Delete all contents of that directory.
3. Restart the IDE.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

1.In your Android studio project change *ndk version*
2.Go to **android>app>build.gradle**

3.Add **ndkVersion  "*add your ndk version number*"**
[ndk version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvfoZ.png)

Answer (score 3):

**1.** From your PC set Show hidden files.

**2.** Go to **C:\Users\NameOfPC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk**

**3.** Delete all the files inside the **folder named 21.1.6352462** it depends on what number you are getting error, it might be 22 or 23  etc. (This is the Version of android) 21 is for Lollipop.

**4.** [Download and choose file from here](https://github.com/android/ndk/wiki/Unsupported-Downloads) - Choose what version you are getting error. Example **android-ndk-r21e-windows-x86_64.zip**

**5.** Extract the file inside **folder named 21.1.6352462**

**6** And run the IDE again.

Image Refence below

[Show hidden folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfYqp.png)

[Show hidden folder 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0jro.png)

[Path folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbD8U.png)

[Website image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7iEZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

I deleted Ndk and Ndk-bundle folder in /Library/Android/sdk

So, the problem fixed.

Probably the ndk version has corrupted

When I deleted that folder, Android Studio replaced it with the latest.

- Go inside your SDK location
- Find the directory called ndk
- Then delete the content inside that directory.
- Then build the app again.

Answer (score 0):

**Root Cause**

This happens when you have at least one version of ndk installed. It might be because of some other project you would have installed it.

The issue happens because the AGP (Android Gradle plugin) used by flutter projects might be above 3.6+.

Android Gradle plugin 3.6+ uses a default ndk version if no version is specified in projects `app/build.gradle` file.

See the official docs here. https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#default-ndk-per-agp

**Solution**

So inorder to fix the above issue. The best solution is to install the default ndk version used by AGP (See the link above) using sdk manager in android studio.

For example:

1. If your AGP version in build.gradle is `4.1.0` then based on above docs link download and install `NDK version 21.1.6352462` from sdk manager.

- If you don't know how to install specific version of NDK see the below link.
  https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#specific-version

Answer (score 0):

[Select Project structure in menu and in sdk location add NDK Path its reolve the issue [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE8fB.png)

Comment: This looks wrong, why would you add NDK path in sdk location.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might get here. This can also be one of the problem situations. First, check here :

```
path-to-sdk/sdk/ndk
```

If there is a version of NDK with all files inside, it means that your NDK is not recognized correctly. Outside of this folder, check the ndk-bundle folder. If this folder exists and a folder named `.installer` is in there. Remove it and try running your project again.

make sure you added `ndk.dir` in your `local.properties` file :

```
sdk.dir= path-to-sdk\\sdk
ndk.dir= path-to-sdk\\sdk\\ndk
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed my app wasn't building and was getting the same error as above.

The error was because the app was looking for `ndk 21.1.6528147` on my local machine but couldn't find it.

I checked my system to know the versions available via `/Users/<your_user>/Library/Android/sdk` and realised I have version 22.1.7171670 so I went to my
`build.gradle` file and added `ndkVersion '22.1.7171670'`

```
android {
     ...
     ndkVersion '21.1.6528147'
}
```

I synced and tried to build my app again and all was fine.